# Can characters be summoned into a unit?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

With the arrival of new summoning spells in the End of Times expansion there is a new spell which allows the wizard to summon a character (worth up to 65 points).

Can this spell be used to summon a character directly into an existing unit or do they have to appear nearby and walk in during the movement phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for Summoning Spells (Nagash Book 1, pg 14) state that *"the Summoned unit must be deployed wholly within the spell's range **and at least 1" away from all other units**, buildings and impassable terrain."*

The Spell *"Kandorak - The Harbinger"* (Nagash Book 1, pg 15) does not state that the charcter summoned has an exception to this rule.